# PHP libevent on Windows

Tags: windows, php, extension

How can I install libevent on Windows? Tryed to make this via PECL but got an error "WARNING: php_bin C:\PHP\php.exe appears to have a suffix .exe, but config variab le php_suffix does not match"

Answer (score 1):

I find this url quite helpful:

http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/

The author made a modified version of libevent and memcached. According to the author, "These projects are based on the existing win32 builds of the two projects. Just fixed so that they work. Neither library has been modified from the respective released version other than to add win32 required changes."

It can be built using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile libevent from [source](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) using Visual Studio command line tools.
You should extract libevent sources somewhere, the cd to that folder and type `nmake Makefile.nmake` there.

Comment: I've got an error: **NMAKE: fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'Makefile.nmake'**

Comment: That's quite odd. It is in a `libevent-2.0.10-stable` folder if you use the latest sources from that site. Could you pls check it again.

Comment: Oh.. My bad - I tryed make this with libevent-0.0.4 from [pecl page](http://pecl.php.net/package/libevent)

Comment: Ok, what's next after nmake finished it's job?